# Jquery validator, add method doesn't accept an array as parameter

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-validate

I have an array called `series` that has elements, but when I print the array as the parameter in function `notEqualSeries`, it shows an empty array.

I have to do that in this way cause I want to use that function with other arrays, so only I would to write the name of the array

```
$.validator.addMethod('notEqualSerie', function (value,element,params) {
        var igual = 0;
        console.log(params)
        params.forEach(function (item) {
              if(value == item){
                  igual++;
              }
        });
        return igual < 2;
    }, 'Serie por ingresar repetida');

 validacion =  $('#formAddEquipos').validate({
     rules: {
            serie: {
                AZ09_: true,
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true,
                remote: {
                    url : base_url + 'menu/serieExiste',
                    async: false,
                },
                notEqualSerie: series
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to insert the variable...

```
notEqualSerie: function() {
    return series;
}
```

Comment: i thought it before, but as i explained in the question, i want to use that added function for other arrays, and i don't want to write the same function several times with different array names